# Angularjs changes dont show up

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to Angularjs. I would like to know what am I doing wrong.

I have an array of elements, which is used by a child directive. In the parent controller if I try to set the array to empty it does not reflect the changes but If i do splice on that array it works.

```
$scope.a = [] // does not work
$scope.a.splice(1,1) // works
```

I even tried to trigger **`$apply`**, but its not working.

Can anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide fiddle with it because conceptually it is not posible.

Comment: Here is a plunk for the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/dWw3OCO2lWb2ajVlzPuX

Comment: the plunker seems working for me, after making a small change:  smartphones: '=wbtable'. So what is the issue then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, this should do what you're looking for.

```js
(function() {
  
  function testDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<div ng-repeat="smartphone in smartphones">{{ smartphone.brand }}</div>',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        smartphones: '=smartphones'
      }
    };
  }
  
  function mainController($scope) {
    $scope.smartphones = [
      { brand: 'Apple', model: 'iPhone 4S', price: '999' },
      { brand: 'Samsung', model: 'SIII', price: '888' },
      { brand: 'LG', model: 'Optimus', price: '777' },
      { brand: 'htc', model: 'Desire', price: '666' },
      { brand: 'Nokia', model: 'N9', price: '555' }
    ];
    
    $scope.remove = function() {
      $scope.smartphones = [];
    }
    
    $scope.splice = function() {
      $scope.smartphones.splice(0,1);
      console.log("splice");
    }
  }
  
  angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('test', testDirective)
    .controller('mainController', mainController);
  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
  <button ng-click="remove()">Remove</button>
  <button ng-click="splice()">Splice</button>
  <div class="row">
    <div test smartphones="smartphones"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment if this is different from what you are after, provide some more specifics so i can alter the code.

Comment: Works and clears few doubts of two way binding too. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Data from parent to child scope is transferred by link during child scope creation, there is no binding. So when you are changing the value of `$scope.a`, child scope still refers to the old value.

There are multiple ways to solve this, but the main idea is to refer to parent's property via some container. E.g. replace at your child `a` to `container.a` and at parent `$scope.a = []` to `$scope.container = {a:[]}`. Also consider `controllerAs` usage whenever possible instead of such containers.

Comment: I included a plunk can you edit it as to what the issue is http://plnkr.co/edit/dWw3OCO2lWb2ajVlzPuX

Comment: @user1624859,  I didn't understand the source of the issue you were having. You can simply use two-way binding, like Joshua suggested